# How does a web application handle submissions?

Tags: web-applications, form-submit, review

For websites where you submit content (like submitting a game to Steam), how is the submission sent exactly? Let me use Steam as the example. When a game is submitted, how does the review confirm/deny it? Do they have their own special program for reviewers on Steam? I'm trying to write a web application where users submit content (such as text) and I review it before it can be posted on the website. Would I create an Administrator account system where all submissions are sent? I'm having an extremely difficult time imagining how these things work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the submission is usually done with http post requests, in which the client application(usually browser), submits the data contained in form, to a sepcified URL, which accepts the data and process them in server side.

for example a comment submit system would have the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="post_comment.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="comment">
<input type="sumbit" value="Sumbit">
</form>
```

When the user clicks the sumbit button the browser construct a http request to post_comment.php, sending the data in the http payload, as name value pair like this:

```
username=AUser&comment=Acomment
```

in the server side the server gets the data and process them(for example store them in a database)

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$comment = $_POST['comment'];
?>
```

As for the administrator account system, yes you can store the values submitted from the user in a temporary table where the administrator can accept/decline it. If the administrator accepts them, move it into the normal table for all the comments, else just drop it.